# npm start not working for react after changing partition directories in windows

Tags: node.js, reactjs

i recently changed my hard drive partitions and merged them into one partition
now when i am trying to starting react from npm start its giving some error so i have uninstalled and reinstalled node js multiple times like 4 times but nothing worked ,

i have created a new react-redux project with `npx create-react-app react-redux`

here is my command line responses

```
PS D:\games&software\software\installed\web-development-folder\www\02\react\react-redux> npm start
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> react-redux@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

'software\software\installed\web-development-folder\www\02\react\react-redux\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
PS D:\games&software\software\installed\web-development-folder\www\02\react\react-redux>
```

one strange thing i have noticed is it is checking for modules in `'D:\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'`
but my project directory is `D:\games&software\software\installed\web-development-folder\www\02\react\react-redux` i feel like this is the main culprit but not sure , after doing too much research i have came for help so please if anyone know what can i do to solve this help me please .

Comment: did u remove ur `node_modules` and reinstalled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is totally unexpected error that the `&` sign was interferring with the url parsing as soon as i have moved my project out of that directory it worked

you can see in the error it was starting the url from 'software\software\installed\web-development-folder\www\02\react\react-redux\node_modules.bin'

but the root folder name is `games&software`
thanks for other answers and i have posted this if someone come to this situation it might help

Answer (score 1):

you can try `npm i` to reinstall all the node_modules that you use. One option could be that they weren't installed properly.

Comment: @Damian Busz  if i have already uninstalled nodejs all global modules will be deleted as well ? if so then yes its all deleted

Comment: and then after fresh install i have created fresh new project and problem is still there